# how to get the error message coming back from Observable and put it in a custom obj? typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, typescript1.8

In my service class I have a behaviour subject (`msg`) that the component is subscribing to, and I have a func that is updating this variable if a data came back from some api call or not.

this is the `msg` declaration:

```
//Message is type Message = {header: string, content: string};
public msg = new BehaviorSubject<Message>(undefined);


private getDataUpdateMessage(listOfPeople: Observable<Person[]>): void {
    let self = this;
    listOfPeople.subscribe(
      res => {
        self.msg.next(undefined);
      },
      error => {
        self.msg.next(error);
      }
    );
  }
```

1st thing is that I dont get how i dont get an error passing `self.msg.next(error);` ? cause im expecting to get there `{header: string, content: string};`

and how do I take the actual message err message and put it there, cause how it looks its not gonna put anything in msg :/

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
private getDataUpdateMessage(listOfPeople: Observable<Person[]>): void {
    let self = this;
    listOfPeople
    .catch(err => Observable.of([new MyError(error)]))
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        self.msg.next(undefined);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: Your custom object. I didn't really understand what you meant by "put it in a custom obj".